# Select type of list using React useState in one function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks

I'm using React useState to show a list of articles for the selected type of article. I've managed to make it work using two separate functions but am wondering if there's a way to put this into one function on the occasion that the user will have many different options to choose from?

```js
function MostReadArticlesList() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(mostReadArticles);
  const [mostReadStyle, setMostReadStyle] = useState(styles["mostReadArticlesHeaderChosen"])
  const [editorsChoiceStyle, setEditorsChoiceStyle] = useState(styles["editorsChoiceHeader"])
  const [rankColor, setRankColor] = useState(styles.mostReadArticlesRankRed)

  function selectMostRead() {
    setList(mostReadArticles);
    setMostReadStyle(styles["mostReadArticlesHeaderChosen"]);
    setEditorsChoiceStyle(styles["editorsChoiceHeader"]);
    setRankColor(styles.mostReadArticlesRankRed);
  };

  function selectEditorsChoice() {
    setList(editorsChoiceArticles);
    setMostReadStyle(styles["mostReadArticlesHeader"]);
    setEditorsChoiceStyle(styles["editorsChoiceHeaderChosen"]);
    setRankColor(styles.mostReadArticlesRankBlue);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.mostReadArticlesListContainer}>
      <div className={styles.mostReadArticlesHeaderDiv}>
        <Button className={mostReadStyle} onClick={selectMostRead}>
          <Icon icon="assets/img/circle-growth-icon.png" />
          <span>Most Read</span>
        </Button>
        <Button className={editorsChoiceStyle} onClick={selectEditorsChoice}>
          <Icon icon="assets/img/notes-star-icon.png" />
          <span>Editors Choice</span>
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.mostReadArticlesList}>
        {list.map((article) => (
          <MostReadArticlesCard
            id={article.id}
            rank={article.rank}
            headline={article.headline}
            date={article.date}
            rankColor={rankColor}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MostReadArticlesList;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are doing there, are you sorting articles with CSS styles? This is bad. You should sort them with JS.

An example of `Array.sort()`:

```
const [list, setList] = useState(articles);

const sortBy = ( property ) = {
    const newList = [...list]; // This is not fully immutable - but should work

    newList.sort( (a, b) => {
        if(a[property] < b[property]) { return -1; }
        if(a[property] > b[property]) { return 1; }
        return 0;
    })

    setList( newList );
}

...

<button onClick={() => sortBy('rank')}>By rank</button>
<button onClick={() => sortBy('headline')}>By headline</button>
```

---

/Edit

One function to manage both lists (you could in theory work with one state), and I would recommend to you using one class `active` for all active buttons instead of "mostReadArticlesHeaderChosen".

```
const [list, setList] = useState(mostReadArticles);
const [active, setActive] = useState('mostRead');

function selectList( listName ) {
    switch(listName) {
        case 'mostRead': {
            setList(mostReadArticles);
            setActive('mostRead');
        }
        case 'editorsChoice': {
            setList(editorsChoiceArticles);
            setActive('editorsChoice');
        }
        default:
    }
}

...

<button 
    class={ active === 'mostRead' ? 'mostReadArticlesHeaderChosen' : 'mostReadArticlesHeader'}
    onClick={() => selectList('mostRead')}
>
    Most Read
</button>
<button 
    class={ active === 'editorsChoice' ? 'editorsChoiceHeaderChosen' : 'editorsChoiceHeader'} 
    onClick={() => selectList('editorsChoice')}
>
    Editor's Choice
</button>
```

Comment: I've pulled the article data from two separate arrays, one for each article list. The user selects a type of list (most read or editor's choice) by clicking on a button and the list of articles is displayed on the page, the styling for each button is also changed to show which option has been selected. I've achieved this using two separate functions and was wondering if there's another way of doing it using just one?

Comment: Thanks! Changed the switch into an if else and the ternary worked!